# Small tables on big screens

Tags: tables, responsive-design, readability

I have a little problem, responsive design and tables with only 3-4 columns, so the tables can't be 100% of the width, because that would result in way too much white space between the columns and pretty bad readability. So we've centered and gave them a max-width.

Now here's what I'm not sure about, what's more readable/easier to orient/navigate in

1) this

[image]

2) or this

[image]

Comment: Um? Both are there..for me anyway http://i.stack.imgur.com/voSxu.png and http://i.stack.imgur.com/KlS6e.png .. tried on a different connection with a different browser and they work as well, gotta be a problem on your side.

Answer (score 4):

The first one.

Compare the eye movement between the 2 of them. This is just based on my opinion. Hope it's useful to you. =)

[image] 
[image]

Comment: Well this means that those headings should be aligned with the table, but what about the background and borders, stretched or not?

Comment: Hi Foxx, the non-stretched are much preferred as it make the screen not as cluttered and more neat. Keep it simple and minimal. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm a bit different, but second option looks more consistent to me. Anyway, there is another problem. Why do you have such a big difference in the font size?

[image]

Table is barely readable. Try to fix this problem and you'll probably get the answer to your initial question.

And yes, second is better, because it looks and feels solid. The first one is a bit broken and looks like a funnel.

[image]

**Update**

I would say: fix alignment/font and you'll get better result.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your insight, font size difference aside, you prefer the second one including the title on the left? Or the mix of the two(bg strechted, title aligned), would be better?

Comment: Regarding font size: if you have extra space, why can't you use bigger font in order to enhance readability?

Comment: That would be question for the designers, we actually had a bigger font size(16px) and it felt way too big so we decreased it to 13, but yeah, maybe something between would be better.

Comment: Ok, I see. Answering your first question: I've described my general impression. Titles will require some attention (I will update the answer in several sec.)

Comment: Because that is a title, and titles are bigger.

Comment: Jop, it is not a problem titles are big. The actual problem text is too small.

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to the interaction on tablets. Full width folding bars (Grafika, Analyze) could be accessible with left thumb, see red areas of gesture interaction. So if you suppose your users will have intensive interaction, this solution could be good.
[image]

Otherwise I'd choose first option, based on my visual perception.

Comment: true but given the resolution on tables, headings(grafika, analyza) would on tablets align with the table anyway